# ActiveRecord Select with Parameter Binding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to use a subquery with ActiveRecord like so:

```
User.select(
    'users.*, 
    (select sum(amount) 
        from subscriptions 
        where subscriptions.user_id = user.id
        and created_at < ? ) as amt)'
).order('amt')
```

However, on the second to last line, I have the problem that I can't figure out how to bind the `Time` class parameter, as `ActiveRecord::Base`'s `select` method doesn't accept more than one parameter (the sql string).  What do I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use one of the [`ActiveRecord::Sanitization` class methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html).

These are mixed into `ActiveRecord::Base` and are almost all protected so they are most easily accessed by defining a class method on your model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.select_with_args(sql, args)
    query = sanitize_sql_array([sql, args].flatten)
    select(query)
  end
end
```

It's also worth looking for other ways to fetch your data and comparing their performance to the subquery method. For example, you could fetch the subscription counts with a separate query:

```
subs_by_user = Subscription.group(:user_id).where('created_at < ?', d).count()
```

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent the use of the prepared statements cache in the db adapter? Looks like http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods/sanitize_sql_array just interpolates the current value into the statement.