# Escape parameters in a query object, using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Given a **query object** (not an AR model)

```
class ComplexQuery
  QUERY = <<-SQL
    ...
  SQL

  def new(param1, param2)
    ...
  end

  def execute
    # format and interpolate parameters into QUERY
    # pass finished SQL to `execute` or `select_all`
  end
end
```

How can I *conveniently* escape all parameters?

**I've succeeded with three techniques**, but none are convenient.

1. Use the `raw_connection` which (for me) returns an instance of `PG::Conn` and call `exec_params`.  I am not satisfied with this because `exec_params` requires a verbose set of arguments for specifying data types.
2. `include ActiveRecord::Sanitization` in my query object and use one of its convenient methods, like `replace_named_bind_variables`.  I am not satisfied with this because `replace_named_bind_variables` is `protected` and I have to use `send`.
3. Write a `module` instead.  For some reason, when I `include ActiveRecord::Sanitization` into a module, I'm able to use its protected methods.  I'm not satisfied with this because I want to instantiate my query object sometimes without executing it, e.g. for testing.

Including `ActiveRecord::Sanitization` into a `class` feels like the best solution, but I must be doing something wrong because I should be able to use a `protected` method.

**I'm looking for a solution that**:

1. escapes multiple parameters
2. is intended to be used by consumers of ActiveRecord
3. infers the data type of a parameter and formats it accordingly

**I was able to find some related questions**

- [Escaping values in Rails (similar to mysql_real_escape_string())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696040/escaping-values-in-rails-similar-to-mysql-real-escape-string) discusses escaping a single value, or suggest `send`ing to private methods.
- Another question ([ActiveRecord Select with Parameter Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062623/activerecord-select-with-parameter-binding)) shows how to use `sanitize_sql_array` in a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base, but my question here is about a separate query object, not an AR model.
- [How to execute a raw update sql with dynamic binding in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483049/how-to-execute-a-raw-update-sql-with-dynamic-binding-in-rails)

Comment: All the methods talked about above uses something from the `ActiveRecord` gem ! It's a bit hard to reason with ActiveRecord without a table or a model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is probably to create a prepared statement using the raw Postgres driver. Unfortunately, ActiveRecord does not expose a way do do this generically. They may add it soon now that mysql2 supports prepared statements. But in the meantime, here's how to do it with the raw `PG` driver in rails.

http://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html#method-i-prepare

```ruby
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
conn.prepare('my_query', 'SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz=$1 OR baz=$2')
result = conn.exec_prepared('my_query', ['param1', 'param2'])
```

Note the use of `$` as the symbol to indicate a positional parameter. The numbers correspond to the parameter's position in the array you pass to `exec_prepared`.

Comment: This is the closest to what the OP is looking for.  I was looking for a generic solution, but the OP did mention Postgresql so this is a fair answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @WayneConrad Yes, hopefully ActiveRecord will move into the modern world at some point, but for now, you should be able to do a similar thing in your driver of choice. The `mysql2` driver in particular recently added support for prepared statements in `0.4.0`.

Comment: `exec_params` is a little easier to use and more appropriate than `exec_prepared` if it is an infrequent query

Answer (score 2):

All the sanitization methods are [already included in `ActiveRecord::Base`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d5902c9e7eaba4db4e79c464d623a7d7e6e2d0e3/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L291) as class methods and supposed to be run as `ActiveRecord::Base#sanitize_***`.

The reason is that all `sanitize_*` functions are driver-specific and rely on `connection` object, which is apparently coming from [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionHandling`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0207464f9b7a00d4916dbd9bc864515524097b7d/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb#L86).

The `ActiveSupport::Concern` contract forces `Sanitization::ClassMethods` module content to become class methods of the class/module that includes `Sanitization`, that is how they become available inside open `ActiveRecord::Base` derived class. They are not made public [IMHO] because they require the connection established, which is usually true for descendants and might be not a case for the `ActiveRecord::Base` itself.

Generally speaking, there is no unambiguous way to do what is asked without the connection (e. g. not in `ActiveRecord::Base` descendant.) Quoting for postgres differs from the one for mysql.

*The summing up:* including `ActiveRecord::Sanitization` into a class/module makes not much sense, since the whole functionality is already presented in `ActiveRecord::Base`. As soon, as one wants to use these quoting functionality without actual connection behind, she is probably to implement her own *quoting functions, mapping to respective `ConnectionAdapter#quote`*.

For the case when the connection is supposed to be established, I would go with prepending a wrapper module to `ActiveRecord::Base` that would wrap protected functions to public (in this module protected functions will be available.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think that the reason the  #sanitize_sql... methods are protected is because they require a connection.  The method #sanitize is public, and it requires a connection the same as the other class methods in the Sanitization module.  However, that a connection is required is a valuable insight.

Answer (score 1):

One things that might be of help to others who write raw sql in rails is `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote` method.

It prevents SQL injection by quoting strings and also cast values for use in raw sql such as converting nil (NilClass) to "NULL" and true(TrueClass) to "TRUE".

Using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote` @justinhoward's answert can be re-written as

```
def quote_value(value)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(value)
end

ActiveRecord::Base.connection('SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz=#{quote_value(param1)} OR baz=#{quote_value(param2)}')
```